# Why Chrome send an empty body while using "fetch()" but Edge sent correctly the body

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'm sending a request using "fetch()" method to another server but the body of the request sent using Chrome is empty.

The application sending the request is a Vue application and the server is using AdonisJS. I've tried my application in Microsoft Edge and the body wasn't empty.

The request in Vue:

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/plain'},
    body: JSON.stringify({username, password}),
};
let req = fetch('http://localhost:3333/user/login', requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
        return response.text();
    }).then(json => {
        this.$refs.debug.innerHTML = json
    })
```

The controller in AdonisJS:

```
async login({request, response}) {
    console.log("params", request.raw());
    return '{"key": "value"}';
}
```

Comment: `application/plain` is not a valid MIME type according to [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application). Can you clarify where you found that specific type?

Comment: Yesterday, I was having trouble with the "CORS" and found on a topic to try putting "application/plain" instead of "application/json" bur I cant remeber which website it was on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/plain'},
```

to

```
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
```

Comment: It worked, thank you, but do you know why do I need to set it to Json in spite of plain ?

Comment: AFAIK there's no such MIME type as `application/plain`, and besides you're obviously sending a JSON: `body: JSON.stringify({username, password})`.

Comment: Yes, I saw @alexander-staroselsky 's comment just after having posted the my comment